# linkedin Ios bundle identifier already taken

Tags: linkedin-api

We are trying to configure the application DriveMeTo to use the linkedin login.
When we try to configure "iOS bundle identifiers:" with "it.drivemeto" value in the linkedin site app configuration page, on clicking Update button we receive the error "Your changes could not be saved right now, please try again." .

Probably the issue depend on the fact that this bundle id is already taken from a previus accout where we have no more access to. Please may you suggest a way to fix this issue? The bundle is legally registered form our company.

Waiting for your answer we wish you a good day.

Comment: contact their support

Comment: Their support is here on stack overflow now.